# How can I make an image cover a table cell completely?

Tags: css, html-table

For some reason the image I have covers all but 1 pixel of the entire table (marked with red) and that ruins the whole design of the page, any idea what can I do to fix it?

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-color: transparent;
}
td.Image {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
td.Image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
div.Text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th height="120px" colspan="4" align="left" bgcolor="ffffff"><font size="8">Title</font>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <td class="Image" height="auto" width="25%" align="left">
      <img src="https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688">
      <div class="Text"><font size="4"><b>Text<br>goes here</b></font>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `padding:0px;` in

```
table,
td,
th {
    border-color: transparent;
    padding:0;
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-color: transparent;
  padding:0;
}
td.Image {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
td.Image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
div.Text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th height="120px" colspan="4" align="left" bgcolor="ffffff"><font size="8">Title</font>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <td class="Image" height="auto" width="25%" align="left">
      <img src="https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688">
      <div class="Text"><font size="4"><b>Text<br>goes here</b></font>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried everything for about two days and nothing worked!

Comment: @AlexTCGPro glad I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tr` to the list and then add `display: inline` to the css.

like this:

```
table, tr, td, th {border-color: transparent; display: inline !important;}
```

Here is a working example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  table,
  tr,
  td,
  th {
    border-color: transparent;
    display: inline !important;
  }
  td.Image {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
  }
  td.Image img {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  div.Text {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
</style>
<table width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th height="120px" colspan="4" align="left" bgcolor="ffffff"><font size="8">Title</font>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <td class="Image" height="auto" width="25%" align="left">
      <img src="https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688">
      <div class="Text"><font size="4"><b>Text<br>goes here</b></font>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```